# Can I make a DIV and its contents visible and invisible with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have DIVs on my form. I would like to use javascript to make these visible or invisible depending on some operation. Currently I am doing this:

```
$('#token2').html("<div style='padding: 2px 4px; -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; border: 1px solid Red;'><span style='color: Red; '>Incorrect</span></div>");
```

and setting the contents of the DIV each time. Is there a way I can set this in CSS and just change a visible property instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show)?

---

Not directly related to your question, but since you mentioned CSS, I'd really recommend just defining the styles outside of the HTML ...embedded in the JS... something like this:

```
#token2 > div {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#token2 > span {
    color: red;
}
```

which simplifies the JavaScript down to

```
$('#token2').html('<div><span>Incorrect</span></div>');
```

although the `.html()` part is really irrelevant anyway, with the previously mentioned jQuery methods.

Comment: One quick question. What's the difference between #token2 div {} and #token2 > div {} ?

Answer (score 2):

$(#token2).toggle() will toggle the visibility, show() and hide() do the specific operations.  Give it the style "display: hidden" to start it off invisible.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.hidden {display:none}

<span id="incorrect-answer"  class="hidden">Incorrect</span>
```

and then use jQuery .addClass and .removeClass to make it visible/invisible

e.g.

```
$("#incorrect-answer").addClass("hidden")
$("#incorrect-answer").removeClass("hidden")
```

Comment: Why would you use this instead of `.toggle()` or `.hide()` and `.show()`?

Comment: because when the page will take time in loading (on slower connection or larger pages), the invisible span or div will be displayed to use initially.  The reason is simple, all the jquery code will not run until the document is fully loaded.  so hiding an element initially from jquery is not a good idea.  Hide it using css.  got it ?

Comment: check here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603645/best-practice-jquery-css-how-to-initialize-hidden-elements-that-will-toggle-v

use the jsfiddle example and see how it runs intially.  Then try to remove the display:none from img style and run it again and you will see the difference

Comment: Sure, you can initially hide it with a CSS class - that's fine. But `.hide()` and `.show()` are still more concise and less typo-prone ways of accomplishing the same end result.